# vue.js .sync can't read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

My child component looks like this:

```
<div>
                <label>Label</label>
                <VTextField
                  :value="addOnLabel"
                  @input="$emit('update:addOnLabel', $event.target.value)"
                  solo
                  outline
                  reverse
                  type="text"
                />
              </div>

props: {
    addOnLabel: {},
  },
```

My parent looks like this:

```
<MultiplierDropDown :addOnLabel.sync="addOnLabel"/>
```

Problem: as soon as I start typing something in the input field, it says `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a `<v-text-field>`, the `@input` event emits the value of the model bound to it.

On a normal `<input>`, you need `"$emit('update:addOnLabel', $event.target.value)"`, but here you just need `"$emit('update:addOnLabel', $event)"`

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing `$event.target.value` with `$event`

Comment: same thing. value of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
@input="$emit('update:addOnLabel', $event.target.value)"
```

with

```
v-on:input.native="$emit('update:addOnLabel', $event.target.value)"
```